# connection between Newton’s method and fixed point iteration

Tags: calculus, fixed-point-theorems

This is from my lecture slide
[image]

[image]

I can understand  Newton’s method, but I don't understand the context in red which requires rewriting th equation $x=g(x)$ as the Newton’s method require the right hand side of the equation to be $x_{n+1}$ rather than $x$?

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish between

- the fixed point equation $x=g(x)$ and
- the fixed point iteration $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$.

There exist several theorems of increasing difficulty starting with the Banach fixed point theorem on when the fixed point iteration actually converges towards a fixed point, i.e., a solution of the fixed point equation. Or more generally on whether a solution of the fixed point equation actually exists.